# Upload file with metadata to SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, document, file-upload, file-metadata

Background:
My requirement is to upload files with metadata from Sales-force to SharePoint online. There should be scheduled job which reads all the attached files from Sales-force and upload it into SharePoint online.

I tried following -

1. Created a client ID and Client secret for Salesforce page and used
   REST API and JS to connect to SharePoint.It did not work and I am
   getting access denied error.
2. Through ADAL JS. I am able to establish the connection between
   Salesforce and SPO but each time I am getting O365 login screen. I
   don't want this login screen.
3. Publish an ASP.Net web API in Azure AD for uploading files. Then
   with REST API call the published web service and send the files with
   metadata. It looks like best approach, but no luck.

Could anyone please help, what should be the approach and any sample code.